# User testing Google Docs addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-docs

I've written a simple Google Docs addon and prior to publishing it, I would like to allow some friends to test. I managed to do that by sharing the project and having another account create his deployment and test but this is too cumbersome.

I looked around and apparently I needed a project in GCP. I opened a project, edited the `OAuth Consent Screen`, and assigned my script to that project. I also added test users under `OAuth Consent Screen`. How do I get those users to install this now and test?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Testing" is a very broad term, and could mean multiple things in this context.

If it's "try it out" then you can publish it privately to your Workspace domain as you don't need to go though the review ([reference](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview#determine_your_audience)). Note though that this only works if you have the Workspace domain. This is usually used for internal tools in companies. Other than that, it has the same requirements as publicly publishing it with the exception of being reviewed by Google ([see process overview](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview)).

If you want them to debug it, you'll have to use the "test deployment", as it has some more tools helping debug errors. You can have a project in a shared drive; this would remove the need to share it manually, but the deployment will have only a single account as its publisher ([reference](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview#:%7E:text=When%20you%20publish%20your%20add-on%2C%20a%20single%20user%20account%20acts%20as%20the%20publisher.)).

### References and further reading

- [Publish an add-on (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview)
- [Test an editor add-on (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons)
- [Create and manage deployments (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments)
- [Update and manage your published add-on (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on)
- [About app review (Google Marketplace guide)](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/about-app-review)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.
For the purpose of this add-on I'm a private person and not part of any organisation. What I want to do is share it with friends&family before I go public and if I understand correctly my options are

1. Share the script and have them run/debug it like I did during development.
2. Just go public.


Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I know. Keep in mind that if there were such workaround, every malicious actor would use it. So I'd say this is a security feature more than anything else.